# How does Ionic Capacitor treat packages in child app from a monorepo?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, capacitor

So I setup a monorepo and have a child app with the following structure:

Ionic-App

- ionic.config.json
- node_modules
- package.json
- apps

  - child-app

    - node_modules
    - ios
    - android
    - package.json

It seems to me that the correct sequence to install a capacitor package is as follows:

1. Go into child and do my install
2. Go into root rebuild node_modules (remove then npm i)
3. Go back into child and run `npx cap sync`

   - this seems to move the dependency from the child package.json and to the root
   - this also seems to update the podfile with the path to root
   - `pod 'CapacitorApp', :path => '../../../../node_modules/@capacitor/app'`

If I don't follow these exact steps the package seems to stay in the child package.json and the podfile links to the child:
`pod 'CapacitorApp', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/app'`

My question is, am I doing this right? I haven't found any docs explaining this process. If someone knows where to find that, can you please link to it?